# Automatically download URL as HTML file instead of visiting the page

Tags: html, jquery

I would like to have a local .html file. When I open it in safari, it will *automatically* download a certain URL as html file.

I manage to get a .html file to download a certain URL as html file, using below code, following instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62966692/4336225).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438864/get-html-content-from-another-site" download >a website</a>
      <script src="./jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $("a[download]").click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
             url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + $(this).attr("href"),
             headers: {
               "X-Requested-With": "true"
             },
             success: function(data) {
               console.log("The data is:", data);
         
               var a = $('<a></a>');
         
               a.attr("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
                 type: 'text/plain'
               })));
         
               a.attr("download", "page.html");
         
               $("body").append(a);
         
               a[0].click();
             }
           });
         
         });
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I also manage to get a .html file to automatically visit a URL, using below code, following instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606541/4336225).

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Start Auto Download file</title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(function() {
         $('a[data-auto-download]').each(function(){
         var $this = $(this);
         setTimeout(function() {
         window.location = $this.attr('href');
         }, 0000);
         });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <p>The download should start shortly. If it doesn't, click
            <a data-auto-download href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer">here</a>.
         </p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I try to combine both code (see below), I get error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.preventDefault')

.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Start Auto Download URL as html file</title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(function() {
         $('a[data-auto-download]').each(function(){
         var $this = $(this);
         setTimeout(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
             url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + $(this).attr("href"),
             headers: {
               "X-Requested-With": "true"
             },
             success: function(data) {
               console.log("The data is:", data);
         
               var a = $('<a></a>');
         
               a.attr("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
                 type: 'text/plain'
               })));
         
               a.attr("download", "page.html");
         
               $("body").append(a);
         
               a[0].click();
             }
           });
         
         }, 0000);
         });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <p>The download should start shortly. If it doesn't, click
            <a data-auto-download href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer">here</a>.
         </p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am too junior to debug it. Please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the correct scope of `this`. You have defined the variable `var $this = $(this);` in the .each function but you in your setTimeout you calling `$(this)` which refers to the setTimeout function which will undefined.

Also you do no need to use `e.PreventDefault` in `setTimeout` function as it will run anyway and there is no default behaviour for that to use `prevent.Default`

In addition we do not need to define `000` in setTimeout just put `0` which means it will run as soon the page is loaded or you can set `1000` so that it wait for `1 seconds` before starting download.

> Working **Codepen** Demo: https://codepen.io/alwayshelping/pen/NWxmERQ

Run snippet below to see the file being downloaded in your browser. (If the snippet is not download the file that means stack-overflow snippet is blocking it) Add this code to in website and it will work fine.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[data-auto-download]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + $this.attr("href"), //this was not called properly
        headers: {
          "X-Requested-With": "true"
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("The data is:", data);

          var a = $('<a></a>');

          a.attr("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
            type: 'text/plain'
          })));

          a.attr("download", "page.html");

          $("body").append(a);

          a[0].click();
        }
      });

    }, 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Start Auto Download URL as html file</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>The download should start shortly. If it doesn't, click
      <a data-auto-download href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer">here</a>.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @halfmoonhalf I am glad to hear that. Happy coding!