# Include one HTML page in another without an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a full HTML document that I'd like to include within an existing webpage on my website. This document is a completely standalone document with its own `<html>` element, its own CSS styles, etc. I do not control this document.

I basically want my webpage to show the normal header/nav of my website, a little bit of metadata about the included HTML document, and then the document itself.

So far I've tried two approaches:

1. **Inserting the document as-is into a div on the page.** Problems:

   - I have to imagine this is semantically wrong in all sorts of ways
   - Styles seem to "leak out" from the inner document and affect the outer content
2. **Put the document into an iframe.** Problems:

   - Links clicked within the iframe only navigate the iframe, not the outer page. I want links to behave as if they were part of the outer page.
   - I'm having a hard time styling the iframe so that it simply extends as far down the page as it needs to to contain the document. I don't want scrollbars -- I just want to dump the whole document onto my page, however large it is.

Is there some other simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this with only HTML and also with client-side Javascript this is not possible. There are ways to get parts of the content of another webpage though. You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11439720/3265307.

Comment: If a question has answers elsewhere on SO it should be flagged as a duplicate. Don't repost answers.